# Persist information between builds in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I've test suite that'll have to run a subset of jobs in a given build. The next build should start off from where the last build left off. Is there a way to persist information within jenkins context? Need to store nextId and retrieve it in the next build.

Comment: There might be a way to do this (like parsing the output of the last build, or something even better) but this seems hacky - what type of information are you trying to persist?

Comment: I'm trying to persist the index. An integer. Say there are 100000 test cases to run, I want to run 10000 per job. The second build should run from 10001 - 20000, to identify the start index, I need a way to persist it somewhere. Is there a common filesystem across builds for jenkins?

Comment: Maybe a [pipeline job](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) ould be a good candidate for what you are trying to do?  Alternatively, perhaps you could paramaterize the start index?